# Should I do a check for null for a ResponseEntity<> object in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, nullpointerexception, response-entity

I'm working with `ResponseEntity<>` in a Spring Boot project and I want to know if it's mandatory to check the responseBody object for null before calling `getBody()`?

For ex:

```
ResponseEntity<Customer> responseBody = customerClient.getCustomer(id);
```

I'm not sure if a `ResponseEntity` object could be null. Can I do directly `Customer customer = responseBody.getBody();` or should I do a check for null before that?

Comment: Are you using Feign Client?

Comment: @minGO, No the client is RestTemplate

Comment: I didn't look in the Spring sources, but I never checked ResponseEntity for being null and never encountered null value for it. I expect an exception to be raised instead of null ResponseEntity if an error occurs.

Comment: The docs don't guarantee, that RestTemplate won't return null, but since the methods are declared to throw `RestClientException` for errors, it should be safe to assume that you won't get null. But `customerClient.getCustomer(id);` seems like a custom method, so it also depends on how it does handle the response/errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to check if responseEntity is null.

Spring is designed to always return a value inside responseEntity. What can be null, is the getBody() method that you call on responseEntity.

You might want to take a look at the following:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html
- https://zetcode.com/springboot/responseentity/